# Converting Image from filepath to base64 in Android does not work on me

Tags: android, base64

So my problem is I need to convert the image from filepath to base64 but when I convert the returned `String` this is what I'm seeing:
[base64 String to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHyBQ.png)

I need to show the real base64 String from the real image.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ImageView ivImage;
        String pathToFile;
        Integer REQUEST_CAMERA=1, SELECT_FILE=0;
        File image;
        TextView textView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE} , 2);
            }

            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();*/

                    SelectImage();
                }
            });

        }

        private void SelectImage()
        {
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Image");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i )
               {
                   if(items[i].equals("Camera"))
                   {
                        dispatchPictureTakerAction();

                   }else if(items[i].equals("Gallery"))
                   {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                       intent.setType("image/*");
                       startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"), SELECT_FILE);

                   }else if(items[i].equals("Cancel"))
                   {
                       dialogInterface.dismiss();
                   }
               }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
        private void dispatchPictureTakerAction()
        {
            Intent takePic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if(takePic.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
               File photoFile = null;
               photoFile = createPhotoFile();

               if(photoFile != null)
               {
                   pathToFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                   Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.thecodecity.cameraandroid.fileprovider", photoFile);
                   takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);

                   startActivityForResult(takePic,1);
               }
            }

        }
        private File createPhotoFile()
        {
            String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_MMmmss").format(new Date());
            File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            image = null;
            try
            {
                image = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", storageDir);


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("mylog", "Except : " + e.toString());
            }
            return image ;
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
                    textView.setText(getFileToByte(pathToFile));




                }else if(requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();


                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        public static String getFileToByte(String filePath){
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
            byte[] bt = null;
            String encodeString = null;
            try{
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                bt = bos.toByteArray();
                encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(bt, Base64.DEFAULT);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return encodeString;
        }
        private String encodedImage(Bitmap bm)
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            return encImage;
        }
    }
```

**This is the result when i convert to base64**

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQ EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/ WAARCBBADDADASIA AhEBAXEB/ 8QAGwAAAwEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAAFCgn/ XABVEAACAAMEBgclAgEEAQIBAhcB AgMREGAhljETMKFRYfAjQnGBkaGxMO NTY8HR4fFSC4MEYpOjs3LDOXSC4/
```

Comment: are you able to generate base64 from an image??

Comment: nope sir, i need to convert the image to base64.

Comment: is your issue solved??

Comment: No sir, i'm still getting same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following to get base64:

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
     byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
     String yourBase64= Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Still the same result, have u tried running the code?

Comment: @Robzkie, What is the issue you are getting??

Comment: I did get the base64 string but when i converted it to image online(in codebeautify) im still getting same results, because what im trying to do is send the base64 to a server and decode it.

Comment: @Robzkie, the length of base64 of image is too long. You cannot copy the whole as it will not show in Log cat. Sometimes it also adds the space into that and will not work to show the image. If you are getting the base64 of the image as string then have you give it try to show that on `ImageView`???

Answer (score 0):

Using bitmap you can get Base64 like this:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
 String encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Or you can get `byte[]` from `File` like this:

```
 public static byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName() + " as it is too long (" + length + " bytes, max supported " + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ")");
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: I still got the same result.

Comment: @Robzkie this code is working for me. I get proper result by this. :) do not try to see image in other website, as you will never get proper Log for Base 64. Because this string is too long.Convert this string again via programatically and u will get back your image